# Push notifications for multiple android and ios apps through gcm / fcm

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

My company is building several Android and iOS apps. They will be essentially the same app but branded differently for each customer.

I am setting up push notifications for these apps. I plan to send all push notifications for both iOS and Android through GCM (or FCM).

I had planned to use only the one single Sender Id / API Key for all apps and all customers.

For iOS notifications to work using GCM or FCM I have to associate an APNS certificate with my Google Project but is it possible to associate multiple APNS certificates with the one Google project if we decide to have just one google project for multiple customers / apps?

If the answer is no, does that force us to have a separate google project for each customer?

Comment: Although ASNS is pretty badly documented you should have a look on it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

A Firebase project can be connected to multiple Android and iOS apps. Each app is defined by its package name or bundle ID. In the case of iOS you can associate a Production and Development certificate with each iOS app you connect to your Firebase project.

So you can use a single Firebase project, to send FCM messages to multiple applications. Note that a Firebase project is built on top of a Google developer project.

Comment: Do you know if uploading certificates can be done remotely too? I want to use this as part of my SaaS.

Comment: At this time no, you can only add your certificates through the Firebase console.

Comment: @ArthurThompson Thanks for the reply, but how do we ensure notifications are filtered depending on the bundleId apps? When all these apps are tied to the same FCM project.                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                     I am new to Android/ FCM and doing a feasibility study right now, Please bear with me if my question is very naive.